# play video in custom keyboardview background for android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way to play a video as a background of a custom keyboard view in android?
i need any resource or tutorials or even apps that has this feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom keyboard can have any view it wants to.  Which could include a video if you wanted.  Just return a layout including a VideoView (or other similar view) from onCreateInputView.

Please note you do NOT have to use KeybaordView.  That's a convenience class for if you have a very standard looking keyboard.  None of the big keyboard makers use it.

Comment: i need a full example of custom keyboard , any ideas?